# Storing Gmail emails on web server: Acceptable or privacy issue?

Tags: android, ios, google-api, gmail-api

I'm trying to come up with an app in which I need to access user's emails for some functionality. I'm getting the normal "View and manage emails" permission from the user for the Gmail access.

I'll be storing the email on the user's device. But is it a problem if I store the details on my own web server too? Is that a data policy violation? Has anyone tried that here?

There are also a few apps which actually do something like this - **[Swingmail](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/swingmail-free-email-app-for/id627868467?mt=8), [Tripit](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.tripit&hl=en), [Boomerang](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.baydin.boomerang&hl=en)**. I know they store data on the device, but there is no way of knowing if they even store data on their web servers.

**Initial research:**

I went through the [Google API TOS](https://developers.google.com/terms/) and below are the 3 things that seem to point that we can store data on the web server:

> [Security](https://developers.google.com/terms/#b-security): You will use commercially reasonable efforts to protect
>   user information collected by your API Client, including personally
>   identifiable information ("PII"), from unauthorized access or use and
>   will promptly report to your users any unauthorized access or use of
>   such information to the extent required by applicable law.
>
> [Retrieval of content](https://developers.google.com/terms/#c-retrieval-of-content): When a user's non-public content is
>   obtained through the APIs, you may not expose that content to other
>   users or to third parties without explicit opt-in consent from that
>   user.
>
> [Prohibitions on Content](https://developers.google.com/terms/#e-prohibitions-on-content): ***Unless expressly permitted by the
>   content owner*** or by applicable law, you will not, and will not
>   permit your end users or others acting on your behalf to, do the
>   following with content returned from the APIs:
>
> 1. Scrape, build databases, or otherwise create permanent copies of such content, or
>      keep cached copies longer than permitted by the cache header;

I think we can still store the data for a user provided user grants permmission for that and the devs takes sufficient measures to protect the data obtained from Google APIs.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure it's a stackoverflow question, but as I've been thinking about this:

1. What does Google say about it?

   - This is in the terms of service, which you have found.
2. What is your relevant data protection laws say about it

   - For example in the UK, you need to consider if you are a data controller, and have taken reasonable measures to secure the data, amongst other things.
   - What is the process you take if you lose the data for instance. There can be financial penalties if you get this wrong.
3. Are your users informed (this is linked to 2)

   - Your users need to have agreed to this, in some acceptable form. How do they remove their data, how long is it held, how is it used.

Now, IANAL, but you have to be careful, you will likely be putting things in a Terms & Conditions, which is a basis of a contract, and there be dragons. For example reasonable in UK law can have a host of pitfalls http://www.linklaters.com/Insights/Publication1403Newsletter/PublicationIssue20070605/Pages/PublicationIssueItem2385.aspx

Bottom line? I'd get a lawyer.